# Python 3.5.2: print("%m"%(mul)) not working

Tags: python-3.x, printing

Hello everyone this is my code:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number:"))
mul = num1*num2
print("Mul:%m"%(mul))
```

It's giving the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/imkaranpatil/Python Training/Basics/Basic_2.py", 
> line 8, 
>  in <module>
>     print("Mul:%m"%(mul))
> ValueError: unsupported format character 'm' (0x6d) at index 5
> ```

Why is this happening? What's the reason? I know that other character formats work. I just want to know the reason behind %m not working.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you exactly what's wrong. Try using a [different format character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting), such as `d`.

Comment: Yeah, different format character is working, no problem with that, i just want to know the reason behind %m not working.

Comment: Because **like the exception is telling you**, `%m` isn't anything it can use. You don't get to pick random letters.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("Mul:%d"%(mul))
```

Comment: Yeah thats working no problem with that, i just want to know the reason behind %m not working.